# ReactJS perform a function before going to the route of link after clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, tailwind-css, inertiajs

I've created my navbar such that, when I open it in a mobile device, body gets `overflow-hidden` class applied. When the navbar is closed, `overflow-hidden` is removed from body.

Problem encountered: The function which removes `overflow-hidden` from body doesn't get run when I click on the link and it navigates to another view. Which means, on the new page, body has overflow hidden so the user can't really scroll anywhere. Opening and closing the navbar fixes that since it removes overflow hidden from the body.

I'm using Laravel Breeze with ReactJS.

```js
// NavLink.js
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";

export default function NavLink({ href, active, children, className = "" }) {
    return (
        <Link
            href={href}
            className={
                (active
                    ? "inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-[#ed8686] text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-[#E05D5D] transition duration-150 ease-in-out dark:text-gray-400"
                    : "inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-500 dark:hover:border-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:text-gray-500 dark:focus:border-gray-300") +
                ` ${className}`
            }
        >
            {children}
        </Link>
    );
}
```

```js
// NavBar.js
import ApplicationLogo from "@/Components/ApplicationLogo";
import DarkModeButton from "@/Components/DarkModeButton";
import NavLink from "@/Components/NavLink";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { MdClose, MdMenu } from "react-icons/md";

const NavBar = ({ dark, setDark }) => {
    const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState("");
    const navRef = useRef();
    const mobileNavRef = useRef();
    const toggleNav = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const navBar = mobileNavRef.current;
        navBar.classList.toggle("active");
        document.body.classList.toggle("overflow-hidden");
    };

    const hideNav = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const navBar = mobileNavRef.current;
        navBar.classList.remove("active");
        document.body.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
    };

    // TODO: Too many renders, change to remove extra renders
    useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollTop >= 80) {
            navRef.current.classList.add("scrolled");
        } else {
            navRef.current.classList.remove("scrolled");
        }
        const onScroll = (e) => {
            setScrollTop(e.target.documentElement.scrollTop);
        };
        window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    }, [scrollTop]);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="main-nav" ref={navRef}>
                <Link to="/" className="h-full w-auto block py-4 mx-auto">
                    <ApplicationLogo className="h-full w-auto" dark={!!dark} />
                </Link>
                <MdMenu
                    className="fixed right-4 top-4 text-lg cursor-pointer lg:hidden dark:text-white"
                    onClick={(e) => toggleNav(e)}
                />
                <ul className="hidden lg:flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                    <li>
                        <NavLink
                            href={route("home")}
                            active={route().current("home")}
                            children="Home"
                            className="text-lg my-2 mx-4"
                        />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink
                            href={route("gallery")}
                            children="Gallery"
                            active={route().current("gallery")}
                            className="text-lg my-2 mx-4"
                        />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink
                            // href={route("about")}
                            children="About"
                            active={route().current("about")}
                            className="text-lg my-2 mx-4"
                        />
                    </li>
                    <li className="cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center">
                        <DarkModeButton dark={dark} setDark={setDark} />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <ul
                className="w-full md:w1/2 lg:w-1/4 flex items-center justify-center fixed inset-0 bg-white h-full flex-col mobile-nav lg:hidden z-50 dark:bg-gray-900"
                ref={mobileNavRef}
            >
                <MdClose
                    className="absolute top-4 right-4 text-lg cursor-pointer lg:hidden dark:text-white"
                    onClick={(e) => hideNav(e)}
                />
                <Link to="/" onClick={(e) => hideNav(e)}>
                    <ApplicationLogo
                        className="h-32 mb-2 w-auto lg:hidden"
                        dark={dark}
                    />
                </Link>
                <li>
                    <NavLink
                        href={route("home")}
                        active={route().current("home")}
                        children="Home"
                        className="text-lg my-2 mx-4"
                        onClick={(e) => hideNav(e)}
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink
                        href={route("gallery")}
                        children="Gallery"
                        active={route().current("gallery")}
                        className="text-lg my-2 mx-4"
                        onClick={(e) => hideNav(e)}
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink
                        // href={route("about")}
                        children="About"
                        active={route().current("about")}
                        className="text-lg my-2 mx-4"
                        onClick={(e) => hideNav(e)}
                    />
                </li>
                <li className="cursor-pointer">
                    <DarkModeButton dark={dark} setDark={setDark} />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

I've made the function `hideNav()` which has `e.preventDefault()` but I'm guessing it doesn't work because it doesn't apply directly on the `Link` tag? I'm not sure

Unsure how to tackle this problem

I've thought about using `useNavigate` but I am not using react router dom, inertiajs is handling the routing for me, I just set the routes in laravel `web.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution,

It's not the ideal solution but this is what I can think of

I added a prop to `NavLink` component and based on if that prop is true, I add onclick event handler that removes overflow class from body

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";

export default function NavLink({
    href,
    active,
    children,
    className = "",
    mobileLink = false,
}) {
    return (
        <Link
            href={href}
            className={
                (active
                    ? "inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-[#ed8686] text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-[#E05D5D] transition duration-150 ease-in-out dark:text-gray-400"
                    : "inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-500 dark:hover:border-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:text-gray-500 dark:focus:border-gray-300") +
                ` ${className}`
            }
            onClick={
                mobileLink
                    ? (e) => {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          document.body.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
                          Inertia.visit(href);
                      }
                    : undefined
            }
        >
            {children}
        </Link>
    );
}
```